# Mysql - Qual seria a query em sql puro que seria equivalente a Laravel sync em uma tabela pivot?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, pivot

Quando trabalho com Laravel em uma tabela pivot onde temos somente os campos `user_id` e `post_id` usamos algo similar a `$user->posts()->sync([3,4])` e a tabela pivot sera atualizada com os posts 3 e 4 para o usuário em questão.

Se esse usuário antes dessa operação possuia os posts 3,8 e 9, ao final da operação ele possuirá somente os posts 3 e 4.

Em um outro projeto onde não uso Laravel qual seria a a query equivalente a essa operação com o sync? Ou seja seria algo que deletasse o post 8 e 9, mantivesse o 3 e inserisse o 4.

Tem como fazer isso em uma só query?

Comment: Então, o Sync faz duas operações delete e insert e se não me engano  select pra ver os itens existêntes. Resumindo não tem como fazer em uma SQL

Comment: Habilite o debug no laravel para pegar os logs do sql que você consegue ter a query exata.